# constant array in c - check if all elements are defined during compile time

Tags: arrays, c, compile-time

i am searching for a way in C, to check during compile-time, if all elements of a constant array are set. Background is, I want to have a lookup-table with named rows and it has to be complete.

Example:

```
typedef enum [foo, bar, bla, max_value} rowNames;

static const uint32 LookupTable[max_value] =
{
    [foo] = 123,
    [bla] = 456, // oops, someone forgot to define the value for [bar]
}

retval = LookupTable[bar]; //this is to read out the value of the lookup table at a certain position
```

In this example, someone forgot to define the value for array element #1 [bar]. I want to make sure during compile time, that all values are defined, and mistakes will break the build.

Of course in reality the table will be larger and more complex, but I think this is enough to get the picture. Especially if the enums will be edited later, it is very likely that enums and table definition may get inconsistent.

regards,
arnschi

Comment: One way: Provide a macro or function that is used to initialise or set the array values.

Comment: Good ideea kaylum, I may try playing around with macros. Just fear since the size of the table is not constant, it may get complicated creating the enum definitions and the table defintion with a variadic macro...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done with just a few modifications do your code.

Change the array to `static const uint32 LookupTable[]` so that its size depends on the number of items initialized. Then initialize the array without designated initializers, just:

```
static const uint32 LookupTable[] =
{
  123, // foo
  456, // bla
  ...
};
```

Now your standard C compiler can check the integrity of the array with a compile-time assert:

```
_Static_assert(sizeof LookupTable / sizeof *LookupTable == max_value, 
               "LookupTable wrong number of items");
```

---

**EDIT :**

For strict control of the data, there's the "X macro" trick, which creates quite ugly code but centralizes all data to a single place in the source. In my example below, all data info is stored in the macro `ARRAY_LIST`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_LIST(X) \
  X(foo, 1)           \
  X(bar, 2)           \
  X(bla, 3)           \

typedef enum
{
  #define FOO_ENUM(name,val) name,
  ARRAY_LIST(FOO_ENUM)
  foo_n
} foo_t;

const int array[] =
{
  #define ARRAY_INIT(name,val) [name] = val,
  ARRAY_LIST(ARRAY_INIT)
};

_Static_assert(sizeof array / sizeof *array == foo_n, 
               "LookupTable wrong number of items");

int main (void)
{
  #define PRINT_ITEM(name,val) printf("%s: %d\n",#name, array[name]);
  ARRAY_LIST(PRINT_ITEM)
}
```

Pre-processor output then gives this:

```
typedef enum
{
  foo, bar, bla,
  foo_n
} foo_t;

const int array[] =
{
  [foo] = 1, [bar] = 2, [bla] = 3,
};

_Static_assert(sizeof array / sizeof *array == foo_n,
               "LookupTable wrong number of items");

int main (void)
{
  printf("%s: %d\n","foo", array[foo]); 
  printf("%s: %d\n","bar", array[bar]); 
  printf("%s: %d\n","bla", array[bla]);
}
```

And program output:

```
foo: 1
bar: 2
bla: 3
```

Comment: Thanks. I would agree, but want to avoid that you have to init the table with knowing the index order. If someone changes the order between foo and bar, you will have wrong values, again without noticing. Keeping the order correct manually is a big source of error, especially if the table becomes big and gets changed in the future...

Comment: @arnschi Either you keep the code strictly in control or you don't. It doesn't make much sense to check for missing array items while at the same time allowing complete re-ordering. There are ways to allow that too, but it involves "X macros" and is generally an ugly solution.

Comment: @arnschi I tossed in the X macro version in the answer, for completeness. It's kind of a last resort since the code turns ugly, but they can be handy when maintaining existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want it to happen at compile time, I think your only option is to create a static code analyzer to do this check, and add it to your toolchain so the verification would be done each build.

At runtime, you could use that entry at the end of the enumeration ('max_value'), and compare it against the size of your lookup table, as long as you change your table definition to be

```
static const uint32 LookupTable[] =
{
    /*[foo] = */123,
    /*[bla] = */456
}
```

This way, the array is auto-sized, and sizeof can be used to see how many entries are in it, so as soon as someone changes the enum, they will at least get a runtime error the next time they run